# Generar select de Bootstrap-select con optgroups + data-subtext

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, array, bootstrap

estoy intentando mostrar un select de empleados con Bootstrap-select usando esta función.

```
function listar_empleados() {
    funcion = "listar_empleados";
  
    $.post("/bureau-veritas/Controllers/EmpleadosController.php", { funcion }, (response) => {
      let empleados = JSON.parse(response);
  
      /* Agrupar empleados por departamento */
      let gruposEmpleados = {};
      empleados.forEach((empleado) => {
        if (!gruposEmpleados[empleado.departamento]) {
          gruposEmpleados[empleado.departamento] = [];
        }
        gruposEmpleados[empleado.departamento].push(empleado);
      });
  
      /* Generar template HTML */
      let template = '';
      for (let departamento in gruposEmpleados) {
        template += `<optgroup label="${departamento}">`;
        gruposEmpleados[departamento].sort((a, b) => (a.nombre > b.nombre) ? 1 : -1)
          .forEach((empleado) => {
            template += `<option value="${empleado.rfc}" data-subtext="${empleado.rol}">${empleado.nombre} ${empleado.apellidos}</option>`;
          });
        template += '</optgroup>';
        
      }
      $('#crearcontrato_encargado_suplente').html(template).selectpicker('refresh');
    });
  }
```

Me retorna este objeto en donde se ordenan a los empleados por departamento

```
{
"Contabilidad": [
    {
        "rfc": "CENAWELIO2023",
        "nombre": "Jonathan",
        "apellidos": "Martinez",
        "departamento": "Contabilidad",
        "rol": "Jefe de departamento",
        "estado": "1"
    }
],
"Industria": [
    {
        "rfc": "FEESHAMOR2023",
        "nombre": "Francisco",
        "apellidos": "Cerino",
        "departamento": "Industria",
        "rol": "Representante Técnico",
        "estado": "1"
    },
    {
        "rfc": "JORGE-ARPAIZ",
        "nombre": "Jorge",
        "apellidos": "Arpaiz Herrera",
        "departamento": "Industria",
        "rol": "Representante Técnico",
        "estado": "1"
    },
    {
        "rfc": "MIGUELNARANJO",
        "nombre": "Miguel Ángel",
        "apellidos": "Naranjo",
        "departamento": "Industria",
        "rol": "Jefe de departamento",
        "estado": "1"
    },
    {
        "rfc": "QUMO0009066E3",
        "nombre": "Oscar",
        "apellidos": "Quevedo",
        "departamento": "Industria",
        "rol": "Auxiliar de departamento",
        "estado": "1"
    }
]
```

}

El problema es que el template que me genera es este de aquí.

[image: Se agrega el mismo empleado para cada departamento]

Ya me aseguré que se esté generando el template adecuado, cosa que sí pasa, pero al representarlo en el Select, pasa eso.

Lo que estoy intentando conseguir es un select como este. Pero en con el nombre de los departamentos, sus empleados y sus roles.

[image]

Comment: No veo diferencia entre tus 2 últimas imagen a excepción del textbox para buscar, es eso lo que deseas eliminar??

Comment: Hola, la imagen que tiene el grupo Picnic y camping es un ejemplo de lo que deseo conseguir. Obviamente con datos de ejemplo, no los que deseo usar.

En la imagen donde aparece el empleado Jonathan Martinez es donde tengo mi problema. Los datos se agrupan correctamente como se puede ver en el objeto que se genera, pero a la hora de generar el HTML dinámicamente, se repite el mismo empleado en los departamentos, no se muestran los demás.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

He dado finalmente con la solución. La solución no ha sido por código como tal.
Tras una investigación un poco exhaustiva, y con algo de suerte, he dado con este hilo de Github: https://github.com/snapappointments/bootstrap-select/issues/2505

En él, mencionan que hay un error en la 14.0beta3 dentro el código de la librería. Un buen samaritano dejó preparada la versión minificada de la librería con el error arreglado en este link; solo hay que cambiar la extensión a .js y usarla en nuestro proyecto.

Link: https://github.com/snapappointments/bootstrap-select/issues/2505#issuecomment-865935670

La generación del código sí era correcta, pero con la versión errónea de la librería, jamás se mostraría correctamente.

[image: 1]

Answer (score 0):

Lo primero, es que me parece raro que puedes hacer `empleados[dep]` sobre un objeto, porque el `json` que tienes como ejemplo es un objeto a modo de diccionario no una lista. La cual se debe pasar a lista usando, por ejemplo `Object.keys(empleados)`

Aquí un ejemplo, yo cree 2 funciones. Una para crear un `optgroup` y otra para crear un `option`.

Recorremos el diccionario, obteniendo el array de key, creamos el `optgroup`, ordenamos la sublista de empleados y la recorremos agregando los `option` al `optgroup`, para finalmente agregar todo al `select`

```js
const OPT={
    title: 'Seleccione un encargado suplente',
    liveSearch: true,
    liveSearchPlaceholder: 'O búscalo aquí...',
    showTick: true,
    allowClear: true,
    deselectAllText: 'Limpiar selección'
};

$('#crearcontrato_encargado_suplente').selectpicker(OPT);
const json= `{
"Contabilidad": [
    {
        "rfc": "CENAWELIO2023",
        "nombre": "Jonathan",
        "apellidos": "Martinez",
        "departamento": "Contabilidad",
        "rol": "Jefe de departamento",
        "estado": "1"
    }
],
"Industria": [
    {
        "rfc": "FEESHAMOR2023",
        "nombre": "Francisco",
        "apellidos": "Cerino",
        "departamento": "Industria",
        "rol": "Representante Técnico",
        "estado": "1"
    },
    {
        "rfc": "JORGE-ARPAIZ",
        "nombre": "Jorge",
        "apellidos": "Arpaiz Herrera",
        "departamento": "Industria",
        "rol": "Representante Técnico",
        "estado": "1"
    },
    {
        "rfc": "MIGUELNARANJO",
        "nombre": "Miguel Ángel",
        "apellidos": "Naranjo",
        "departamento": "Industria",
        "rol": "Jefe de departamento",
        "estado": "1"
    },
    {
        "rfc": "QUMO0009066E3",
        "nombre": "Oscar",
        "apellidos": "Quevedo",
        "departamento": "Industria",
        "rol": "Auxiliar de departamento",
        "estado": "1"
    }
]
}`;

function createOptGroup(label){
  let opt = document.createElement("optgroup");
  opt.label=label;
  return opt;
}

function createOpt(value,text,subtext){
    let opt = document.createElement("option");
    opt.setAttribute("data-subtext",subtext);
    opt.value=value;
    opt.innerText=text;
    return opt;
}

function listar_empleados() {
  
  //la agrupación acá
  
  
  let gruposEmpleados  = JSON.parse(json); //no colocar esto, es solo para la demo
  
  const select = document.getElementById("crearcontrato_encargado_suplente");

//destruir el select
 $('#crearcontrato_encargado_suplente').selectpicker('destroy');
 select.innerHTML="";
 
 
  for(let dep in gruposEmpleados){
      let group = createOptGroup(dep);

      gruposEmpleados[dep].sort((a, b) => (a.nombre > b.nombre) ? 1 : -1);
      
      for(let e of gruposEmpleados[dep]){
        let opt = createOpt(e.rfc,`${e.nombre} ${e.apellidos}`, e.rol);
         group.appendChild(opt);
      }
      select.appendChild(group);
  }
 
  $('#crearcontrato_encargado_suplente').selectpicker(OPT);
 
 }
  listar_empleados();
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.0.0/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.12.9/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.0.0/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap-select@1.14.0-beta3/dist/css/bootstrap-select.min.css">
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap-select@1.14.0-beta3/dist/js/bootstrap-select.min.js"></script>

<select id="crearcontrato_encargado_suplente">
<option>1</option>
<option>2</option>
<option>3</option>
</select>
```

Comment: 1. En la solución que propones, me da error usar .sort(), haciendo console.log() para verificar que empleados[dep] sea un array retorna false.

2. A la hora de mostrar tus resultados, se repiten los elementos. Por eso usaba .html() .

3. Respecto a lo que dices del manejo de la información, la solución que propuse fue esa para tener los datos ordenados. En una lista comprendo que debería hacer una comprobación al generar el template. Con el diccionario, todo al estar organizado sería solo cuestión de iterar el objeto resultante.

Comment: @OscarQuevedo Te respondo en orden: (1) Algo pasará con tu implementación, yo creo que el json que pusiste no está bien, eso lo tienes que ver tú, porque como verás la demo no tiene errores. (2) Se repiten porque tu pones en tu función `.selectpicker('refresh')` y no `.selectpicker()`, yo pensé que lo tenías por algún motivo, he editado la respuesta para que lo veas.

Comment: (3) A lo que me refiero ( y tiene que ver con el punto 1), es que tu elemento raíz del JSON es un objeto NO una lista. Los objetos se encierran con `{ }` y las listas con `[ ]`, y los objetos no tienen función `forEach`, pero en tu código tienes `empleados.forEach((empleado) =>` esto no es posible con el JSON que tú has puesto, por eso yo tuve que transformar ese objeto a lista usando `Object.keys(empleados)` y por eso creo que tu error del punto 1 proviene a que tenemos JSON distintos

Comment: Entiendo. Ahora que lo pienso, tienes razón en el uso de .forEach(), e inconscientemente siempre lo he usado hasta el momento al hacer peticiones al servidor. Como dices, al hacer la petición está retornando un json, pero el objeto que yo puse fue el resultado de hacer el ordenamiento en grupos, que en este caso, fueron los departamentos. Respecto al ```.selectpicker('refresh')```, lo puse así porque mi select ya está instanciado, así que solo toca refrescarlo cuando se hace un cambio.

Comment: El objeto pertenece a las líneas que tienen el comentario /* Agrupar empleados por departamento */, para evitar confusiones.

Comment: @OscarQuevedo Es decir `gruposEmpleados` es la variable que contiene el objeto que yo interpreté como el JSON?

Comment: Exactamente. Para reafirmar, mi petición retorna un JSON originalmente que con el ordenamiento termina siendo un diccionario.

Comment: @OscarQuevedo Edité el código (cambios menores), para que se ajuste al tuyo, favor pruébalo y si ha resultado. En todo caso, creo tu problema estaba en que tenías esto `.selectpicker('refresh')` y debería ser esto `.selectpicker()`. Recuerda aceptar la pregunta si es correcta, y si no me avisas

Comment: Puse a prueba la solución, y el problema persiste. Honestamente no sé qué es lo que pueda estar generando esto, porque el HTML de la solución inicial sí genera el HTML correctamente en código, pero ya en la vista no se muestra igual. Me rindo con esto de momento, por lo que usaré el data-subtext para mostrar a qué departamento pertenece mis empleados.

Comment: Respecto al ```.selectpicker('refresh')```, en tu solución usas ```.selectpicker()``` porque lo necesitas para crear la instancia. En mi caso la instancia la tengo creada en otra parte con otras opciones, por lo que tiene el aspecto ```.selectpicker({ opciones })```. La documentación menciona el uso de 'refresh' cuando se hacen cambios para refrescar el select, sólo para aclararlo.

Comment: @OscarQuevedo Pero puedes destruir el select, he actualizado el código para que veas como sale.

Answer (score 0):

Debido a que aún no logro dar con la solución, he optado por usar los data-subtext para mostrar el departamento del empleado. Sólo por cuestiones de tiempo, pero en cuanto pueda, actualizaré el post.

La solución:

```
function listar_empleados(){
    funcion = "listar_empleados"

    $.post('/bureau-veritas/Controllers/EmpleadosController.php', { funcion }, (response) => {
        let empleados = JSON.parse(response);
        let gruposEmpleados = {};

        /* Agrupar empleados por rol */
        empleados.forEach(empleado => {
            if (!gruposEmpleados[empleado.rol]) {
                gruposEmpleados[empleado.rol] = [];
            }
            gruposEmpleados[empleado.rol].push(empleado);
        });

        console.log(gruposEmpleados);
        /* Ordenar grupos por orden alfabético */
        let gruposOrdenados = Object.keys(gruposEmpleados).sort();
        let gruposEmpleadosOrdenados = {};
        gruposOrdenados.forEach(rol => {
            let empleadosOrdenados = gruposEmpleados[rol].sort((a, b) => {
                if (a.nombre + a.apellidos < b.nombre + b.apellidos) return -1;
                if (a.nombre + a.apellidos > b.nombre + b.apellidos) return 1;
                return 0;
            });
            gruposEmpleadosOrdenados[rol] = empleadosOrdenados;
        });

        console.log(gruposEmpleadosOrdenados);
        /* Generar template HTML */
        let template = ``;
        for (let rol in gruposEmpleadosOrdenados) {
            gruposEmpleadosOrdenados[rol].forEach(empleado => {
                template += `<option value="${empleado.rfc}" data-subtext="${empleado.departamento} - ${empleado.rol}">${empleado.nombre} ${empleado.apellidos}</option>`;
            });
        }

        $('#crearcontrato_encargado_suplente').html(template).selectpicker('refresh')
    });
}
```

El resultado:

[image: 1]

Respecto al uso de .selectpicker() y .selectpiker('refresh).

Cuando se tiene una instancia previamente establecida, solo se ocupa llamar al método refresh cuando se hacen cambios en el select.

```
$('#crearcontrato_encargado_suplente').selectpicker({
    title: 'Seleccione un encargado suplente',
    liveSearch: true,
    liveSearchPlaceholder: 'O búscalo aquí...',
    showTick: true,
    allowClear: true,
    deselectAllText: 'Limpiar selección'
})
```

Comment: Puedes destruir el select con `$('#crearcontrato_encargado_suplente').selectpicker('destroy');' y volver a crearlo (ver el ejemplo en mi respuesta). Por otro lado, fíjate que tu pregunta es sobre colocar `optgroups`, por lo que tu respuesta no puede ser no colocarlos.

Comment: Hola. En eso tienes razón, sin embargo es para un proyecto escolar no muy serio. Es un detalle menor que yo quería implementar, pero por falta de tiempo muestro esta alternativa. Cuando tenga algo más de tiempo exploraré la solución a profundidad.

Comment: El sitio es de preguntas y respuesta, tú te puedes valer de ello y pedir ayuda en forma de pregunta. No interesa si la pregunta es relativo a un proyecto escolar, empresarial o simple curiosidad. Por esto las respuestas deben ir enfocadas a responder la pregunta. En tu caso el fondo de la pregunta es colocar un `optgroups`, y tu respuesta no responde a tu pregunta. Finalmente en tu proyecto puedes optar por el camino que tu gustes, pero eso no lo hace una respuesta valida

Comment: Por otro lado, y esto a modo personal, si el asunto no es importante, entonces no generes una pregunta, el tiempo de los demás es tanto o más valioso que el tuyo. Ten respeto